# How to align center Label in JavaFX / FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml

How can I center the text of a Label in javafx ? In the .css stylesheet or directly in the fxml.

I tried `Label { -fx-text-alignment: center;}` in the .css but it does not work. Even in the scene builder it does not work.

Comment: What is the parent of your Label in your FXML?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha an AnchorPane

Comment: Do you have multiple lines of text in the label, or is the text all on one line?

Comment: I just have one line. I want to put an username on that label

Comment: The [`textAlignment` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty) is only relevant for multiple lines of text. It defines how each line is aligned in the rectangle that holds all the lines of text (basically a justify property).

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, I didn't know that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

1. Use a layout pane that can center the label, and let the label be its "preferred size" (i.e. just big enough to hold the text), or
2. Make the label fill the entire width of its container, and set its alignment property to center.

You said in the comments that you're using an `AnchorPane` as the label's parent. This generally isn't usually a particularly good choice for a layout pane (essentially you have to hardcode the bounds of each control), and you can't center things in it (not without a large amount of work, anyway). So with an anchor pane as parent, you are reduced to choice 2:

```
label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(label, 0.0);
AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(label, 0.0);
label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Obviously, all that can be set in FXML too.

In general, though, I would recommend using a more appropriate [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) and setting the appropriate properties on that layout pane to center the label.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, I changed the AnchorPane to a VBox and I worked :)

Comment: @James_D What if we don't add the 1st line? I omitted 1st line and it worked.